# Scraping nested html with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm looking for some help with scraping with selenium in python.
You need a paid account to view this page so creating a reproducible won't be possible.

[The page I'm trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WA8S.png)

I'm attempting to scrape the data from the pitch in the top right corner of the image under 'Spots on Field'.

```
<div class="player-details-football-map__UEFA player-details-football-map">
<div class="shots">
<div>
   <a class="shot episode" style="left: 39.8529%; top: 28.9474%;"></a>
   <div class="tooltip" style="left: 39.8529%; top: 28.9474%;">
      <div class="tooltip-title">
         <div class="tooltip-shoot-type">Shot on target</div>
         <div class="tooltip-blow-type">Donyell Malen </div>
         <div class="tooltip-shoot-name"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tooltip-time">h Viktoria Koln</div>
      <div class="tooltip-time">Half 1, 18:22 02/09/20</div>
      <div class="tooltip-time">Length: 7.1 m</div>
      <div class="tooltip-shoot-xg">Expected goals: 0.17</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The above is a snippet of just one of the data points I want to scrape.

I've tried using BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = 'https://football.instatscout.com/players/294322/shots'
response = get(url)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

shots = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'tooltip')
print(type(shots))
print(len(shots))
```

and nothing was being returned.

So now I've tried using Selenium.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\James\OneDrive\Desktop\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://football.instatscout.com/players/294322/shots')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys('my username')
driver.find_element_by_name('pass').send_keys('my password')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "hRAqIl", " " ))]').click() 
goals = driver.find_element_by_class_name('tooltip')
```

but I'm getting the error of

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".tooltip"}

Can someone please help point me in the right direction? I'm basically trying to scrape everything from the above HTML, that includes 'tooltip' in the class name.

Thanks

Comment: Is every data point a `<div>` with children `a` and `div`, or are the data points all sibling `a`s and `divs` within the single `<div>`?

Comment: Every data point is a <div> with children a and div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using css selectors with `bs4`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re #for extracting offsets
r = [{**dict(zip(['left', 'top'], re.findall('[\d\.]+', i.div['style']))), 
      'shoot_type':i.select_one('.tooltip-shoot-type').text,
      'name':i.select_one('.tooltip-blow-type').text,
      'team':i.select_one('div:nth-of-type(2).tooltip-time').text,
      'time':i.select_one('div:nth-of-type(3).tooltip-time').text,
      'length':i.select_one('div:nth-of-type(4).tooltip-time').text[8:],
      'expected_goals':i.select_one('.tooltip-shoot-xg').text[16:]}
     for i in soup(html, 'html.parser').select('div.shots > div')]
```

Output:

```
[{'left': '39.8529', 'top': '28.9474', 'shoot_type': 'Shot on target', 'name': 'Donyell Malen ', 'team': 'h Viktoria Koln', 'time': 'Half 1, 18:22 02/09/20', 'length': '7.1 m', 'expected_goals': '0.17'}]
```